# Trim and Lowercase PHP value from MySQL

Tags: php

I am using a PHP/MySQL page to query a database and then place the data in values for later output like below.  Using the [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) PHP Man page I can see how to turn $city to lowercase, which is great because the directory is case sensitive. How do I make the value for $City lowercase AND trim to only display the first 6 characters?

This is what I have so far:

```
$csv_output .= "images/".strtolower($City)."/".$jpg_name."_1.jpg";
```

Comment: easy points for someone.

Comment: Don't forget the whitespace in city names (i.e. New York) or such nice towns like ['s-Hertogenbosch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27s-Hertogenbosch) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first 6 characters:

```
$csv_output .= "images/".strtolower(substr($City, 0, 6))."/".$jpg_name."_1.jpg";
```

*man*: http://php.net/manual/it/function.substr.php